# regex help to remove a +

Tags: python, regex, bash

I am having a problem with a + sign. 
Here is my format of my CSV

```
wifichannelnumber+ssid+macaddress of AP
```

Here is an example of a good line

```
6+Jills-Equinox+78:61:7c:19:xx:xx
```

And here is the problem mine. Note the + next to S8.

```
11+Samsung-Galaxy-S8+-4469+a2:cc:2b:8d:xx:xx
```

I would like to remove plus in bash or python (Edit) for a whole CSV

Comment: And what about your current try/solution isn't working?

Comment: So, `+` is your field divider and you have an unquoted `+` in the data which breaks the format, haven't you?

Comment: If you want to match a `+` in any generic regex format (without needing to know whether it's BRE or ERE ahead of time), `[+]` is the appropriate syntax. So, in sed: `sed -i '' 's/-S8[+]-/-S8-/g' filename.csv`

Comment: ...that said, tagging with a bunch of languages/tools just because you think those *might* be useful to solve a problem is bad form. If you just want a solution that works in UNIX, whether it uses bash or sed or awk or Python or whatever, just tag `unix` and let folks answering the question suggest the appropriate tool for the job.

Comment: (It's also good form to *show what you tried* and how it failed -- that gives us an idea of where you got stuck, and thus more precisely where guidance is needed).

Answer (score 0):

```
phone = "11+Samsung-Galaxy-S8+-4469+a2:cc:2b:8d:xx:xx"
print(phone.replace("S8+","S8"))
>>>11+Samsung-Galaxy-S8-4469+a2:cc:2b:8d:xx:xx
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your desire regex is:
`^(\d+)\+(.*)\+(([\w\d]{2}\:){5}[\d\w]{2})$`

Then you can use python to remove every '+' sign in the second regex group

Answer (score 0):

**`Python`** solution:

```
s = '11+Samsung-Galaxy-S8+-4469+a2:cc:2b:8d:xx:xx'
if s.count('+') > 2:
    parts = s.split('+')
    s = '{}+{}+{}'.format(parts[0], ''.join(parts[1:-1]), parts[-1])

print(s)
```

The output:

```
11+Samsung-Galaxy-S8-4469+a2:cc:2b:8d:xx:xx
```